# Difference in PCA between psych and Factorminer functions

Tags: r, pca

I'm currently trying to understand the difference between the `PCA$scores` from the principal function of `psych` and the `PCA$ind$contrib` from the PCA function by `FactoMiner`.

Both cases I get the same number of rows, which are the number of observations, but the values are quite different.

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example to demonstrate the discrepancy?

Comment: Unfortunately these data are not mine, nor the code SaS I'm trying to replicate, I need the results from a 'PROC FACTOR' analysis (e.g. factor1 factor2 and so on..) I can show  few rows of results of mine.

Comment: You can create an example using one of R's [many publicly available data sets](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/datasets/html/00Index.html).